# Passing value to a HREF in a Razor view in ASP.Net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

```
   <a href="@(Html.MyActionHref(controllerName: "MyController", actionName: "MyAction"))">
```

The above line generates a hyperlink for Razor view. The html helper method MyActionHref() creates the link. On clicking the link it calls an action method from controller. Now suppose the action controller method which this link calls is parameterized i.e.
`public ActionResult MyAction(string myParams){}`
(The html helper method MyActionHref() is even overloaded to accept three parameters accordingly.)

**How this additional parameter can be passed to the controller action method from the model?**
Say,

```
<a href="@(Html.MyActionHref(controllerName: "MyController", actionName: "MyAction",params: new {....} }))">
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Why are you using such helper when you can simply:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "some text", 
    "MyAction", 
    "MyController", 
    new { myParams = "Hello" }, 
    null
)
```

which will generate the proper anchor tag:

```
 <a href="/MyController/MyAction?myParams=Hello">some text</a>
```

Comment: What if myParams needs a model.myValue?

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to just do... new { myParams = Model.myValue } ?

Comment: If this code is inside a Jquery function then how can I  pass a var for myParams instead of "Hello"

Answer (score 7):

You could either use the `Url.Action` method, or copy its behaviour.

```
@Url.Action(
   controllerName: "MyController", 
   actionName: "MyAction", 
   routeValues: new { id = 1 }
);
```

Have a look at the signature of that method to find what you want to do.